# Finding music that was purchased only

Tags: google-play-music, google-play

My Google Play Music library consists of both songs that I've uploaded to the cloud and songs that I've purchased. I am trying to delete all the music I've uploaded, but keep the music I purchased.

Is it possible to display only purchased songs or only uploaded songs?